# calling parent View controller from segue view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, segue

Will the following design result in a memory leak?

CatVC modally segue to CatDetailVC. Then upon closing, CatDetailVC calls a method inside CatVC as

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    CatVC *parent =(CatVC *)self.parentViewController;
    [parent segueToDogVC];
}];
```

Although I never imported `CatDetailVC.h` into CatVC, the thing is I do a segue to it. Further, I had to call `CatVC.h` inside of CatDetailVC.

Answer (score 0):

If you segued from CatVC to CatDetailVC, why do you need to call method from CatDetailVC on  CatVC. You can simply unwind segue, that's the safest.